# List all trips from a particular user to another user that has not yet reviewed

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm using PostgreSQL. I have this following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  id int PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE trips (
  id int PRIMARY KEY,
  driver_id int,
  FOREIGN KEY driver_id REFERENCES users(id)
);

CREATE TABLE trip_passengers (
  id int PRIMARY KEY,
  user_id int,
  trip_id int,
  FOREIGN KEY trip_id REFERENCES trips(id)
  FOREIGN KEY user_id REFERENCES users(id)
);

CREATE TABLE feedbacks (
  id int PRIMARY KEY,
  trip_id int,
  rater_id int,
  ratee_id int,
  review TEXT,
  FOREIGN KEY trip_id REFERENCE trips(id),
  FOREIGN KEY rater_id REFERENCES users(id),
  FOREIGN KEY ratee_id REFERENCES users(id),
  UNIQUE (trip_id, rater_id, ratee_id)
);
```

Here are the following rules:

- Trip can contain multiple passengers (through trip_passengers table).
- User can only make a review if they made a trip together.
- Drivers can make a review to a passenger.
- Passenger can also make a review to a driver.
- Passenger can make a review to a passenger.

Cases:

Table: **users**

```
| id  | username   |
|-----+------------+
| 1   | driver     |
| 2   | passenger1 |
| 3   | passenger2 |
```

Table: **trips**

```
| id  | driver_id |
|-----+-----------+
| 1   | 1         |
```

Table: **trip_passengers**

```
| id  | trip_id | user_id |
|-----+---------+---------+
| 1   | 1       | 2       |
| 2   | 1       | 3       |
```

Let say I want to get all trips from driver that with passenger1 that not yet reviewed. That would return trip#1.

If driver make a review to passenger1, and run again the query, it will return nothing.

Same case for passengers, if I want to get all trips of passenger1 with passenger2 that has not yet reviewed, I will get trip#1, since they both ride the same trip.

How can I return all trips from a particular user to another user that has not yet reviewed?

Here is my last attempt but some cases were not met.

```
SELECT trips.* FROM trips
  INNER JOIN trip_passengers AS t1 ON t1.trip_id = trips.id
  INNER JOIN trip_passengers AS t2 ON t1.passenger_id = :rater_id AND
    t2.passenger_id = :ratee_id AND t1.trip_id = t2.trip_id
  LEFT JOIN feedbacks ON feedbacks.trip_id = trips.id AND
    feedbacks.rater_id = t1.passenger_id
  WHERE feedbacks.review IS NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

With this design, your requirements are not enforced. Any user can make a feedback for any other user, regardless of whether the reviewer or the reviewed participated in the trip!

Here is an suggestion:

**Users**

```
CREATE TABLE users
( user_id int PRIMARY KEY
) ;
```

**Trips**

```
CREATE TABLE trips
( trip_id int PRIMARY KEY
) ;
```

**Trip_participants** (passengers and drivers)

```
CREATE TABLE trip_participants
( trip_id int,
  user_id int,
  PRIMARY KEY (trip_id, user_id),
  FOREIGN KEY trip_id REFERENCES trips (trip_id),
  FOREIGN KEY user_id REFERENCES users (user_id)
) ;
```

**Trip_drivers**

```
CREATE TABLE trip_drivers
( trip_id int,
  driver_id int,
  PRIMARY KEY (trip_id, driver_id),
  UNIQUE KEY (trip_id)                -- optional, to enforce that a trip
                                      -- has only one driver.
  FOREIGN KEY (trip_id, driver_id) 
    REFERENCES trip_participants (trip_id, user_id)
) ;
```

**Feedbacks**

```
CREATE TABLE feedbacks
( feedback_id int PRIMARY KEY,
  trip_id int,
  rater_id int,
  ratee_id int,
  review TEXT,
  UNIQUE KEY (trip_id, rater_id, ratee_id) ,
  FOREIGN KEY (trip_id, rater_id) 
    REFERENCES trips(trip_id, user_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (trip_id, ratee_id) 
     REFERENCES trips(trip_id, user_id),
  CHECK (rater_id <> ratee_id)
) ;
```

and the missing `trip_passengers` would be a View:

**Trip_passengers**

```
CREATE VIEW trip_passengers AS
  SELECT trip_id, user_id
  FROM trip_participants
  WHERE (trip_id, user_id) NOT IN
        ( SELECT trip_id, driver_id
          FROM trip_drivers
        ) 
;
```

---

Finally, the query to return all trips that have not been yet reviewed:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM trips AS t
WHERE t.trip_id NOT IN
      ( SELECT trip_id 
        FROM feedbacks
      ) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

If any number of reviews are accepted as reviewed trip then this should do it.

```
SELECT * from trips 
where t.id not in 
    (SELECT distinct(t.id)
    FROM trips t, feedbacks f
    WHERE t.id = f.trip_id)
```

Using subquery selecting all reviewed trips and then selecting trips not in reviewed trips.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    trips a
            INNER JOIN  feedbacks f
                on a.ID = b.trip_id
            LEFT JOIN trips c
                on a.ID = c.ID
WHERE   c.ID IS NULL
```